# How bind "Alt+space" hotkey to a slot in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying bind some "actions" (connect to a slot) on this hotkey `Qt::ALT + Qt::Key_Space` without success (((((.

Other combinations work fine without additional effort. For example `Qt::ALT+Qt::Key_Return`.

```
<!-- language: lang-cpp --> 
QShortcut* ptrHotKey = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::ALT + Qt::Key_Return), this);
connect(ptrHotKey, SIGNAL(activated()), this, SLOT(testSlot()));
```

Attempts to catch `keyPressEvent` fail; they even don't go through that handler.

On Windows systems they call system menu by default `"Restore", "Move", "Size", "Minimize", "Maximize", "Close"`.

Comment: Windows is routing those. What do you want to bind it to? Surely you want to let Windows users use the standard shortcuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your desktop environment's window manager uses that shortcut for something, Qt won't even receive the event.  As noted by David Heffernan you should be able to access it through your DE API though.

Comment: Well, it will go through the windows window proc. So you can no doubt intercept it through platform specific code. Hard to imagine why anyone would want to do that.